# How to populate an array with multiple strings input by the user?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to get some strings from user and then put them in an array, and afterwards find the longest string and print it in reverse.

For the first part I wanted to know if the array in the following example is OK or not, so I decided to print its elements but the result is not correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n;
    puts("How many strings do you want to enter ? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char strings_array[n];//the array that I want to save strings in
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//getting strings from user
    {
        printf("Please enter string number %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &strings_array[i]);
    }
    //print the elements of array to test if it works or not
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", &strings_array[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char strings_array[n];` is an array of characters. Not an array of "strings"

Comment: @Mani Aghaie You need a two-dimensional character array.

Comment: The quick fix would be `char strings_array[n][100];` or so. Noting that it's not usually a good idea to allocate large arrays locally on the stack.

Comment: You really don't need to store every single string, just the longest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [*string*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) in C is a contiguous sequence of non-zero bytes, followed by the zero byte (the null-terminating byte, `'\0'`).

[`char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types#Character_types) is a type representing a single character - exactly one *byte*.

`char strings_array[n];` is a [variable-length array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) of *n* bytes, really only suitable for holding one *string*, with a string length of at most *n - 1* characters (you must always leave room for the null-terminating byte).

(*Note: if the user is clever enough to enter a value less than one, this program invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by declaring an array whose size is less than one. Additionally, the user may enter a very large value, potentially exhausting your programs [automatic storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration). It is a good idea to validate user input.*)

So to have an array of multiple strings, you must really create an array of arrays (or an array of pointers, but let's focus on the former for now).

`char strings[n][16];` would be an array of *n* arrays of 16 bytes each. It would be capable of holding *n* strings (each with a maximum string length of 15).

This is sometimes referred to as a *two-dimensional* array, which makes it easy to visualize. Let's say `n=4`, then this array can be visualized as the following, where every *cell* is a single byte:

```
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

If you asked the user to populate the first two *sub-arrays* (as in `scanf("%15s", &strings[i])`), and they entered `hello` and then `stackoverflow`, the array would look like this:

```
[ h][ e][ l][ l][ o][\0][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[ s][ t][ a][ c][ k][ o][ v][ e][ r][ f][ l][ o][ w][\0][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

A working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void fatal(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("How many strings do you want to enter? ");
    if (1 != scanf("%d", &n) || 1 > n || n > 32)
        fatal("Invalid size specified.");

    char strings[n][64];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Please enter string #%d: ", i + 1);
        if (1 != scanf("%63s", strings[i]))
            fatal("Invalid string input.");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        puts(strings[i]);
}
```

Note how we always check the return value of `scanf` is the expected number of successful *conversions* (`%d` is *one* conversion specifier, so if the return value is not `1` an error has occurred).

Additionally note that we limit the amount of data `scanf` can read with `%s` by specifying a *maximum field-width* as `%63s`, which is the longest string our array can hold (the size of the array minus one, leaving room for the null-terminating byte). Without specifying this limit, `scanf` can read more data than our array can store, leading to a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

Program I/O:

```
How many strings do you want to enter? 2
Please enter string #1: hello
Please enter string #2: stackoverflow
hello
stackoverflow
```

Comment: Thank you so much your answer was so complete . Thanks for the time that you spent.